# Oшибка при вызове нескольких SQL запросов

Tags: python, sql, pandas

Пытаюсь выгрузить данные из БД:

```
import pandas as pd

# connection = my connection to DB
df = pd.read_sql(sql, connection)
print(df)
```

script.sql

```
set session calendar = iso;
with cte_emp(weekstart, weekend) as 
(
    select
        min(calendar_date) as weekstart,
        max(calendar_date) as weekend
    from sys_calendar.calendar as cl
    where cl.year_of_calendar >= 2020
    or cl.calendar_date in ('2019-12-30', '2019-12-31')
    group by week_of_year, year_of_calendar
)
select * from cte
```

В итоге получаю ошибку:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' is not iterable

Однако всё работает без первой строчки в SQL запросе.

Подскажите, как выгрузить данные, но не убираю первую строку в SQL запросе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция [pd.read_sql()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) ожидает на вход **один единственный** SQL запрос.

Т.е. один `SELECT ... statement`.

`set session calendar = iso;` - это настройка параметров сессии и не имеет ничего общего с запросом.

Попробуйте воспользоваться [sqlalchemy.orm.Session](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

# an Engine, which the Session will use for connection
# resources
engine = create_engine('postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost/')

# create session and add objects
with Session(engine) as session:
    session.execute('set session calendar = iso')
    ...
```