# Подключение sqlalchemy к Teradata

Tags: sqlalchemy, teradata

Пытаюсь подключиться к терадате через `sqlalchemy` , что бы реализовать ранее созданный мною [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1296219/o%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-sql-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Код подключения:

```
engine = create_engine('teradata://'+dr['login']+':'+dr['password']+'@'+dr['server']+'/'+'mydb_name'+'?driver='+dr['driver'])

data = engine.execute('select 1')
print(data)
with Session(engine) as session:
    session.execute('set session calendar = iso')
    data = session.execute(sql_query)
    print(data)
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'cache_key'
```

Так же пробовал `create_engine` без драйвера. Получаю следующею ошибку:

```
raise DatabaseError(i[2], u"[{}] {}".format(i[0], msg), i[0])
sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (teradata.api.DatabaseError) (1207, '[HY000] [TPT]
[ODBC PostgreSQL Wire Protocol driver]Connection refused. Verify Host Name and P
ort Number., [TPT][ODBC PostgreSQL Wire Protocol driver]Invalid attribute in con
nection string: DBCNAME.')
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/4xp6)
```

Подскажите, что я упускаю ?